# Linux kernel 3.0.0-15-generic problem help needed

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I'm new with all this Ubuntu and Linux programs so please bear with me.

My niece gave me her laptop she got from a tutor program and asked me to fix it since it didn't boot all the way. So the problem is once I select Ubuntu with Linux `3.0.0-15-generic` from the GNU GRUB (Ver 1.99-12ubuntu5) loads up the `initramfs` prompt. What do I do from there?

I've typed exit and it gives me the following message:

```
[ 85.199633] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[ 85.199689] Pid: 1; comm: init Not tainted 3.0.0-15-generic #26-Ubuntu
```

There's a whole bunch more lines listed, but hopefully this will give you an idea.

Any help would be much appreciated. Should I just download the new version of Ubuntu and reboot the whole thing? If so, can someone give me the step by step instructions?

Comment: Yes, downloading/burning the latest 12.04 ISO to a CD on a separate computer and reinstalling would be the easiest option. You would also upgrade Ubuntu this way.

Answer (score 0):

As izx said in the comments, downloading the iso and reinstalling would be easier.

Since you are new to Ubuntu, you might want to read the installation instructions first: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop.